# issues timing the thread functions of pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads, time.h

So i am having an issues calculating the elapsed time of the thread function of each thread, I need to be able to find the time total elapsed time for all of the threads but it is not performing this properly. (see output below code)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int numthread;
double x1;
double x2;
double h; 
double totalintegral;
int n;              //number of trapezoids
int localn;

double gnolock;
double gmute;
double gbusy;
double gsema;

double doTrapRule(double localx1, double localx2, double h, int localn);
double doFunction(double x);
void *threadCalc(void* threadid);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    x1 = 0.0;
    x2 = 20.0;
    n = 200000;

    numthread = 10;

    pthread_t* threads = malloc(numthread*sizeof(pthread_t));

    h = (x2 - x1)/n;
    localn = n/numthread;

    for(i = 0; i < numthread; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void *) &threadCalc, (void*) i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numthread; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Trap rule result with %d trap(s) is %f\n", n, totalintegral);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("no lock completed in %f\n", gnolock);
    exit(0);
}

void *threadCalc(void* threadid)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    double localx1;
    double localx2; 
    double localintegral;
    int cur_thread = (int)threadid;

    localx1 = x1 + cur_thread * localn * h;
    localx2 = localx1 + localn * h;

    localintegral = doTrapRule(localx1, localx2, h, localn);

    totalintegral = totalintegral + localintegral;
    //printf("Trap rule result with %d trap(s) is %f", n, totalintegral);
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double time_elapsed = (long double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time elapsed of each thread %f\n",time_elapsed);
    gnolock = gnolock + time_elapsed;
    return NULL;
}


double doTrapRule(double localx1, double localx2, double h, int localn)
{
    //time start here
    double localtrapintegral;
    double tempx1;
    int i;

    localtrapintegral = (doFunction(localx1) + doFunction(localx2)) / 2.0;

    for(i = 1; i <= (localn - 1); i++)
    {
        tempx1 = localx1 + i * h;
        localtrapintegral = localtrapintegral + doFunction(tempx1);
    }

    localtrapintegral = localtrapintegral * h;
    //time end here, add elapsed to global
    return localtrapintegral;
}

double doFunction(double x)
{
    double result;
    result = x*x*x;

    return result;
}
```

output:

```
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.010000
time elapsed of each thread 0.010000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
time elapsed of each thread 0.000000
Trap rule result with 200000 trap(s) is 40000.000001
no lock completed in 0.020000
```

As you can see for whatever reason only someone of the threads are actually returning a time. I ran this multiple times, and every time only a few threads returned a result. Just as FYI gnolock is my variable that stores the total amount of time elapsed. My guess as to why this isnt working is because the decimal point is out of range, but it shouldnt be?

Comment: It looks like you are running into clock resolution problems.  What OS is this?  (What kernel + version number + architecture)

Comment: this is going to complicate things but, I am SSH into a comal cluster, how can I get that information for you? is there a way to get that from the terminal?

Comment: Who knows?  I don't know what a "comal cluster" is, what OS it's running, etc.

Comment: Linux comal.cs.tcu.edu 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 23:56:34 BST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

If you call `clock()` on your system, it has a resolution of 10 ms.  So if a process takes 2 ms, then it will usually report a time of 0.00s or 0.01s, depending on a bunch of things which you have no control over.

Use one of the high resolution clocks instead.  You can use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` or `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, I believe the resolution of this clock is several orders of magnitude better than `clock()`.

See `man 2 clock_gettime` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely thing is that your clock tick is too coarse for the elapsed time you are trying to measure.  Mostly start and stop clocks are the same. Occasionally, by chance a clock tick occurs during your thread execution and you see 1 tick.  (This is effectively what Dietrich said above).

As an example of what this means, imagine your thread takes an hour to complete and your clock ticks once a day, at midnight. Mostly when you run the thread is starts and ends on the same day. But if you happen to run it within an hour of midnight, you will see the start and stop on different days (1 tick).  What you need then is a faster clock, but such a clock might well not be available.

Comment: how can i solve/fix that issue? is there another method is should try to use?

Comment: I don't know whether you can. I'd imagine that the clock tick is the best resolution available, but others will know better.  The other option is to make the elapsed time bigger (eg loop) if you are just experimenting. Why do you need to measure the time elapsed?

Comment: what i am doing is measuring the time difference between different critical section locking methods to see which is best to use,  i want to see how long it takes for the whole thing to finish. should i just putting the start before the create for loop and the stop after the join loop?

Comment: @StraightEdge: You are doing it wrong.  When you are measuring the performance of a multithreaded system, you should probably be measuring wall time instead of CPU time.

Comment: @DietrichEpp how do i measure the wall time then? i know how to do it in MPI using wtime....but how do you do that with pthreads?

Comment: @StraightEdge: Just write a program, and run it with the `time` command.  It will report the `real` time taken.  Make sure your program runs for at least a few seconds.

Comment: i dont know if it will even run for a few seconds though, that why i was trying to evaluate it, in terms of milliseconds, but would microseconds make this any easier to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tool. `clock` doesn't measure the elapsed time but

> The clock() function returns an approximation of **processor time** used
>   by the program.

these are two completely different things. Perhaps your threads don't use up much of processor time.